# Angular 2: can custom component handle its own events?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I built an Angular 2 component and I have a doubt: is there a standard that defines if the events triggered inside the component should be broadcasted (vie @Output, for example) or the component can handle them itself?

Let me show some code:

the component may be called *content-detail* and the template is:

```
<ion-card (click)="navigate()">
    <h3>{{ rawcontent.name }}</h3>
</ion-card>
```

the .ts has a navigate() method, and inside it I call some route (in my case it's an Ionic 2 app, which uses NavController, but it could be anything else).

```
@Component({
  selector: 'content-detail',
  templateUrl: 'content-detail.html'
})
export class ContentDataComponent {
  navigate() {
   //do seomething, like navigate to another page
  }
}
```

Is this a good practice?
Or the best is that the component use EventEmitter to emit it to it's parent (as explained [here](https://toddmotto.com/component-events-event-emitter-output-angular-2), for example)
I can't find any documentation about it. What I guess is that it would be easy to test the component if it simply emit the event to the parent instead of navigate (or do anything else), because I wouldn't need to inject some router or navcontroller.
Could anyone help?

Comment: Not sure what your question is about. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html explains most component-to-component communication scenarios

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer what I want to know if is a standard do this communication to avoid that a custom component do something that is not its responsibility (in this scenario, navigate to another page).

Comment: Sorry, it's not really clear to me what the question is about. Is it about the `(click)="..."` or is it about `@Output()` that you mention. What purpose would this output fulfill?

Comment: Maybe I'm not explaining it in a proper way. A new explanation: is it ok that a custom component that is used in different other components handles a click event inside it and make the app goes (navigate) to another page, or should it (the custom component) emit an event to the parents and let the parents decide what to do?

Comment: I don't think there is a general answer which way is right. It depends on the use case. In general there is nothing wrong with directly handling the click event.

Answer (score 0):

- `(someEvent)="someMethod()"` is a common way to handle events in templates
- `@Output() xxx;` is for communicating from child to parent
- for all other scenarios use a shared service
- for communication between siblings there is a shortcut using template variables

```
<my-a-comp #a></my-a-comp>
<my-b-comp (someEvent)="a.someMethod()"
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use host listeners like :

```
@Component({
selector: 'content-detail',
templateUrl: 'content-detail.html'
})
export class ContentDataComponent {
  @HostListener('click') onClick() {
    // do navigation ...
  }
}
```